# Как создать 2-х мерный массив из строк?

Tags: массивы, php

Добрый день,

Есть текстовый файл с таким содержимым:

```
ключ1|значение1
ключ2|значение2
ключ777|значение777
```

Как мне создать массив, поместив в первый элемент массива `$arr['key']['value']` соответственно `ключ1` и `значение1`, и так со всеми элементами?

Спасибо.

Comment: [Ассоциативный массив][1]


  [1]: http://www.php.su/learnphp/datatypes/?array#assoc

Comment: традиционно: зачем вопрос оформляется кодом?

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
    $content = file_get_contents('application/Data/file1.txt');
    $Data = explode("\n", $content);
    $x=0;
    foreach($Data as $value)
    { 
        $Stroka= explode('|',$value);
        $arr[$x] =array('Key'=>$Stroka[0],'Value'=>$Stroka[1],'File'=>'Файл');
        $x++;      
    } 
    print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$str = explode("\n", $text );
$array = array();
foreach($str as $val){ 
    $str_t= explode('|',$val);
    $array[$str_t[0]] = $str_t[1];     
}
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Пиарю функцию [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php) – читает из файла строку значений через разделитель:

```
$result = array();
if (( $handle = fopen( "hashcode.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (( $data = fgetcsv( $handle, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE) {
        if( count( $data) != 2) continue; // нам нужно ровно два элемента
        $result[ $data[0]] = $data[1];
    }
    fclose( $handle);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`$f = file('file.txt');
for ($i=0;$i<count($f);$i++){
  $s = explode('|',$f[$i]);
  $ar[$s[0]] = $s[1];
}`

в $ar - будет ваш массив

Comment:  * что, если файл 1Гб, а оперативки на хостинге 192Мб?
 * что, если в строке не окажется разделителя?